# angular 7, attribute selector, prevent clearing existing content

Tags: angular

When I use selector as attribute, then the injected content completely clears previous content of the tag, for example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s2nykd

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
            <p attrib>
              Start editing to see some magic happen :)
            </p>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent  {
}

@Component({
  selector: '[attrib]',
  template: `<p>my-comp works!</p>`
})
export class MyCompComponent {}
```

as a result, there will be the following:

```
<p attrib>
  <p>my-comp works!</p>
</p>
```

therefore, all previous content: `Start editing to see some magic happen :)` - was deleted.

Please tell me how to make the previous content is not cleared.
This is the result I want to get:

```
<p attrib>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
  <p>my-comp works!</p>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider using transclusion with the `<ng-content>` [NgComponentOutlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet)
 tag to "merge" the content:

```
@Component({
  selector: '[attrib]',
  template: `
    <p>
      my-comp works!
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </p>
  `
})
export class MyCompComponent {}
```

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8q2bgv) in action.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Well, your answer is better I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Directives](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives) if you want to append HTML.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kaotfs)

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[attrib]'
})
export class MyDirective implements OnInit {
  tag: string = 'p';
  template: string = 'my-comp works!';
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2, @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const child = document.createElement(this.tag);
    child.innerHTML = this.template;
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.el.nativeElement, child);
  }
}
```